# Getting available networks via NetworkManager D-Bus interface

Tags: networking, networkmanager, d-bus

I'm looking for how I can find the available networks (like from `nmcli dev wifi list`) using the D-Bus interface.

Looking at the [API](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.2/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html) I don't see any Properties or Methods. I'm wondering if it is possible to get this info from the D-Bus interface? I know I can get this from `wpa_supplicant` but your not able to talk to `wpa_supplicant` when `NetworkManager` is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all that nmcli does it achieves by using the D-Bus API. Like most NetworkManager clients.

The API documentation is here: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/spec.html#dbus-interfaces

See the `/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/*` objects. Also, the Wi-Fi device has a property `AccessPoints`. See https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Wireless.html .

Also, you may first need to trigger a scan. See the `LastScan` timestamp on the device.

And finally, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to talk to wpa_supplicant, only to get the current scan list. At least if you don't interfere with what NetworkManager is doing, it should work. However, I would only talk to NM.